# How to a Setup TURN server on Amazon Web Services EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, turn, coturn

I am trying to setup a TURN server on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance.
I am successfully able to create and run a TURN server using COTURN.

But I am not able to connect to my TURN server. I am pretty sure I might have missed to enable some Ports on Inbound rules or using a wrong name/IP to connect.

Could some one please tell me whats all necessary configuration that i should do after running the turn server?

Answer (score 1):

Is the EC2 instance launched in a private subnet or a public subnet?

Check the Security Groups associated to the instance, have you whitelisted your IP address on the port necessary?